# Field not found: System.Text.Reg­u­lar­Ex­pres­sions.Regex.in­ter­nal­MatchTime­out

Tags: .net, regex, .net-4.5

We are running into the issue described here: [field-not-found-exception-with-net-4-4-5-compiled-regexes](http://www.codinginthetrenches.com/2013/field-not-found-exception-with-net-4-4-5-compiled-regexes/)

In short: I tried to build a .Net 4.0 assembly on a machine that has been updated to .Net 4.5. So I am targetting .Net 4.0. When trying to run this assembly on a machine that only has .Net 4.0 installed, I get the following exception: Field not found: ‘System.Text.Reg­u­lar­Ex­pres­sions.Regex.in­ter­nal­MatchTime­out’.

If I build the same assembly on a machine that has *not* been updated to .Net 4.5 I can run the generated assembly on a .Net 4.0 machine without any issues. In other words: the .Net 4.0 assembly that is generated on a .Net 4.5 machine is *not* the same as the one generated on a .Net 4.0 machine.

The assembly provides precompiled regular expressions.

I can solve this by either:

1. Building de assembly on a .Net 4.0 system.
2. Upgrading the target machine to .Net 4.5.

There are however issues with both solutions:

1. We build assemblies for various targets, including WinRT. We are now facing the problem that we cannot use a single machine for building all of them, which complicates our build/test process.
2. The produced assemblies are shipped to customers. They will not all be pleased if we tell them to upgrade to .Net 4.5, in order to use a 4.0 assembly.

Do any of you know of a better solution, other than getting rid of the precompiled regular expressions?

Comment: do you really need `regex`! You can instead use string methods where are also efficient.But that really depends on the input you are trying to match..Give us some info on your input and the `regex` you are using to match.

Comment: Well, in the end we can always avoid regex I guess. Thanks for the offer, but if we really need to, we know how to do it. However: this is existing code, with regex-es all over the place. So if there is no need to rewrite the code, we would like to avoid that. Especially since this issue is basically not our fault, but rather the result of Microsofts inability to keep things working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a backward compatibility bug of either .NET 4.5 itself or Visual Studio. And it's [rather old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456779/field-not-found-exception-with-compiled-dll-regular-expression), if we can judge from a first issue date, and isn't resolved to the date (have you all .NET and VS updates installed on 4.5 system? ). If it's not patched by now, then I would go with solution 1 (can't expect MS will fix the bug fast).

Comment: I was afraid someone might say that. It is a pity, but a solution nonetheless, so I will mark it as such. BTW: yes the 4.5 system has all the latest updates. It is my developing machine, whereas our official build machine is still on 4.0. We just happened to not have built this particular assembly on a 4.5 machine before. Which is why we are encountering this (rather annoying) issue now. If anybody comes up with a better solution, please do not hold back...

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question but I assume you are calling Regex.CompileToAssembly, in which case what happens underneath is an assembly is generated which is tightly coupled to the runtime it was produced on so if you ran that on .NET 4.5 then it will have references to the new 'in­ter­nal­MatchTime­out' field. Beyond always generating that assembly on the .NET 4.0 runtime (solution 1) have you considered compiling them on first use and caching them?

```
RegEx re = new Regex(pattern, RegExOptions.Compiled);
```

then you can simply cache all the RegEx's you need in your app. While that will give a little bit of a perf hit on first use it will prevent a lot of jumping through hoops in your builds.

Comment: We did consider that in the past, before this issue popped up. This may indeed be a better solution than building on a .Net 4.0 machine. Not sure yet though whether it will lead to performance issues (will have to try).

Comment: Please let me know if this approach works for you or not. I'm interested in any reasons why this might not work for you.

Comment: After moving to a new build machine, I finally picked this up again. The code above does _not_ solve the issue. It seems that the compiler optimises this to a compiled regex at build time. What helps is avoiding the Compiled flag. I have not yet seen serious performance differences, but I must say that we still have to evaluate that further. [Microsofts info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg578045(v=vs.110).aspx) is utterly unclear. If you read that, it actually suggests that the JIT compiler also gets involved in interpreted expressions.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement :**
While browsing any `.svc` file in IIS, I was getting error like

> "**Field not found:
>   'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.internalMatchTimeout'**"

**Solution :**
I have repaired the existing `.NET` framework (in my case 4.5.2) and restarted the server, it started working.